# Is it better to invalidate a session in a servlet in which it is declared or in the jsp page where its values will be used?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, invalidation

Is it better to invalidate a session in a servlet in which it is declared or in the JSP page where its values will be used ?

I am posting the code of servlet below -

```java
package Controller.UploadInfo;

import File.FileOperations;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import Controller.DatabaseException.*;


public class AttendenceInfoUpload extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            HttpSession session;

            if (FileOperations.fileUpload(request)) {

                try {

                    FileOperations.excelToAttendence();  

                    request.getRequestDispatcher("UploadSuccess.jsp").forward(request, response);


                } catch (DBException e) {

                   session = request.getSession(true);
                   session.setAttribute("exception",e);

                   request.getRequestDispatcher("FileUpload.jsp").forward(request, response);

                   session.invalidate();
                }

            } else {

                session = request.getSession(true);
                session.setAttribute("exception"," File Upload Failed " );

                request.getRequestDispatcher("FileUpload.jsp").forward(request, response);

            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

In the given servlet above I have invalidated the session right after the `getRequestDispatcher()` in the catch block. Although the code is working, my concern is will it cause the exception message to loose before it can be displayed in the JSP page. Or is it better to invalidate the session declared in the servlet in the JSP page where its values will be displayed.

The JSP page -

```jsp
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import = "java.io.*" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Excel File Upload Example</h1>

        <form name="form1" method="post" action="AttendenceInfoUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table border="1">
                <col width="120">                                
                <tr>
                    <td>Upload Excel File:</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="Select File"/></td>
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input name="" type="submit" value="upload" /></td>                    
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>        

        <c:if test="${not empty exception}"> 

            <label>
                <font color="red">   

                <c:out value="Error:${exception}"></c:out>

                </font>            
            </label>                                                    
        </c:if>        

    </body>    
</html>
```

One can suggest an alternate solution as well?

Comment: Why do you invalidate the session in the first place? Why do you store in the session attributes that are of interest for this request only? Why don't you store them in request attributes?

Comment: A session isn't declared in a servlet. It is *maintained* by the servlet container. Where you invalidate it is up to you. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably to invalidate the session in the servlet but make sure that any values required by the JSP are stored in the request rather than in the session. I say this because it is best practice to put all logic in beans or servlet code and keep JSPs for layout only.

Comment: Your conclusion doesn't follow from your premiss.

Comment: How so? I mean not in JSP because JSPs are for layout and invalidation of a session is more aligned with logic.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to invalidate a session. Also there's no need to use a session attribute. If you want to forward to a error page you can use request attribute. Using a session heavily is a bad practice because it requires a lot of memory to utilize those variables you put into it.

```
} catch (DBException e) {
    request.setAttribute("exception",e);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("FileUpload.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

as I said it's not a good practice to invalidate a session when you are going to forward to a error page. Even if JSP page is rendered in the same thread other threads that can use the same session might not work. And you can't use session variables after the session is invalidated. However it's rarely happens but other request might invalidate a session while JSP is rendered.

Comment: And what circumstance are you talking, I can't read it from the question.

Comment: I am not using a separate error page. The JSP page (given in the example above ) is both an input page as well as displays the error received from the servlet during the input operation. It is dynamic in nature. At first run it displays no error but when an error happens it shows in a label at the bottom. My problem was that when I did not invalidate the session, even on running it a new the old session value was still being displayed at the bottom. So should I not use the HttpSession session object in the servlet , or should I go for request attributes in the above case ?

Comment: You shouldn't, use request attribute, invalidate session in another servlet and redirect to the login page.

Comment: Why not ? The above task is just a small part in the functionalities of the user profile. I cannot logout after completing the task in the servlet. Is there any sideeffects, limitations in using request attributes ? Someone else in another post in this website relating to request attribute said they are used frequently in MVC web application.

Comment: They are limited to the request scope.

Comment: @EJP The session is invalidated when you no longer need it, like I'm doing when the user log out. Your comment is not constructive here, in general it could be everything. You should provide the case when a session needs to invalidate concretely.